# consumir o webservice em WCF com ajax

Tags: ajax, web-service, wcf

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <input type="text" id="codUser"/>
        <button onclick="ConsUsuario(); return false;">Consulta Usuario</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConsUsuario(){
        var value = $("#codUser").val();

        $.ajax({
        url: "http:/food-fast-com.web27.redehost.net/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo",
        type: "GET",
        data: JSON.stringify(value),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.info(result);
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

da o erro `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404` , como se não encontrasse o caminho do webservice, mas no soapUI funciona blz.

Comment: Tente utilizar o script desta forma, alterando sua passagem de parâmetros para a URL. 

`function ConsUsuario(){
        var value = $("#codUser").val();

        $.ajax({
        url: "http://food-fast-com.web27.redehost.net/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo/" + value,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.info(result);
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: Leandro funcionou, porem apresentou outra mensagem 'Method not alowed', porem no header esta correto:

Comment: Leandro não deu erro porem o retorno do console foi : 'Object {ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult: Object}', mas se eu consulto pelo browser a mesmo url que foi gerada o retorno é: {"ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult":{"Codigo":2,"CodigoSetor":1,"Login":"ednilson1","Nome":"Ednilson","RegistroAtivo":true,"Senha":"123456","Tipo":"D"}}, vi que no servidor nao esta com permissao para (*), entao testei em localhost pelo browser com a URL: http://localhost/ServiceRestPub/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo/2 que esta com permissão para todos os methodos

Comment: Bem, o retorno do seu webservice está correto. Agora você só precisa utilizar o seu objeto, acredito que dentro do seu método **success** você pode acessar o objeto retornado seguindo o exemplo: 
`success: function (result){alert(result.ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult.Codigo);}`

Comment: funcionou @LeandroAraujo, valeu amigao pela ajuda!